# Groovy - Regex match the string with last char numbers

Tags: java, regex, groovy

My input string

```
pdfe_bc
pdfe_orSE
pdfe_oo1
pdfe_och1
pdfe_oo2
pdfe_och2
pdfe_oo10
pdfe_och10 and so...
```

I want to collect the below-formatted string and stored in a separate ArrayList.

```
pdfe_oo1
pdfe_oo2
pdfe_oo10
```

I'm using below regex to find and match the string

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[pdfe_oo]\\d+")
```

and my complete code is

```
for ( WebElement e : allIDs ) {
    String iD = e.getAttribute("id")
    println iD
    Matcher m = p.matcher(iD)
    if(m.matches){
        formID.add(iD)
    }       
}
```

But it's getting below exception

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: matches for class: java.util.regex.Matcher
```

import

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher
import java.util.regex.Pattern
```

Comment: Why don't you use Groovy?  `if (iD ==~ /pdfe_oo\d+/) { ... }`

Comment: @Wiktor Thanks a lot I'm a beginner in groovy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use Groovy directly to test the whole string against a regex using `==~` operator (it requires a full string match as `String#matches()` in Java does) and make sure you remove square brackets from the regex (as `[abc]` matches a single char, either `a`, `b` or `c` and not an `abc` substring):

```
if (iD ==~ /pdfe_oo\d+/) { 
    formID.add(iD) 
}
```

Note the use of slashy string (`/pdfe_oo\d+/`) that allows using a single backslash to define regex escapes.